# Making cutouts and Concave Shapes

Tags: modeling

I'm making a pan flute that consists of two joined parts, the top one and the bottom one.

For the top one, I modeled a plane and several tubes. I wanted to know the cleanest way to making cutouts and joining everything in a single mesh, so that underneath there is the negative space of the tubes.

thank you!

Here's the tube, with the concave part:
[image: isolated tube]

And the flute seen from above:
[image: photo from above]

[image: view from above]

[image: view from below]

Comment: Hello, do you have a picture of the real object? Do you want it to be concave underneath?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added for clarification @moonboots, thank you!

Comment: so maybe join the different parts instead of creating a plane below?